# How to do a angular material list with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, list, angular-material

I'm wondering how to implement an md-list with 3 lines of text in each list item plus a checkbox and the possibility to click (i want to show a detail panel).is this possible without custom css?
Here is an example of how it should work, but the layout is somehow broken.

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <md-button ng-click="showSideNav()">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
      <h3> {{item.who}} </h3>
      <h4> {{item.what}} </h4>
      <p> {{item.notes}} </p>
    </div>
    </md-button> 
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

http://codepen.io/steffi80/pen/MaqLGW

perhaps anybody can help.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare which controller the ShowSideNav() function is under.

When the button is clicked, the controller 'admin' runs the 'dailyUsageReport' function. In this case, the function gets data, and applies it to my $scope.

($scope.dailyUsageReport = dailyUsageReport;)

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="admin.dailyUsageReport();"><a href="#">Your Text</a></button>
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding,but my problem is how to fix the layout of the list.

Comment: I see in the codepen how it is displayed now, without editing or overriding materialize I'm not sure that there is. Not sure if this helps, but removing "text align: left" displays all of the text centered.